# Why is SVG path occasionally drawn incorrectly in this piechart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg

I'm trying to create SVG piecharts in a Rails app. I've written a method that works most of the time, but occasionally produces an odd result.

[image]

This chart is being built correctly, except for 1 segment!

The SVG code that produces that segment is

```
<path d='M0,0 L99.99949084376563,0.3191096796332688 A100,100 0 **0,0** 99.99893303088741,0.46194445996738664 Z' fill='#136F7F' />
```

And I think the cause of the problem may be the values I've wrapped with `**` (The stars are not present in the actual code!).

I'm building the chart with the following method, where supplies `data` as a hash of key-value pairs.

```
svg = "<svg viewBox='-100 -100 200 200'>"
data.each do |d|
svg += "<path d='M0,0 L#{previous_x},#{previous_y} A100,100 0 #{x <= 0 ? 1 : 0},#{y <= 0 ? 1 : 0} #{x},#{y} Z' fill='#{col[i]}' fill-opacity='1' />"
end
svg += "</svg>"
```

`x` and `y` are the cosine and sine of the segment's angle in radians, multiplied by 100.

Am I setting the correct `large-arc-flag` and `sweep-flag` values, and are these what is causing the occasional segment to fail?

Comment: the segment you posted is not equal to the segment in the sreeenshot... the start point is roughly the same as the endpoint...

Comment: thanks @HolgerWill, I will need to regenerate the code to check this as I've been hacking away. I will edit the question. In the meantime, can I check that my understanding is correct. If the pie segment is >50%, then the large-arc-flag should be 1, otherwise 0, correct? But I think my issue lies with the sweep-flag. Under what conditions should sweep flag change? I don't fully understand the specs! From what I can see a pie should only ever need 2 of the 4 combinations - 1,0 or 0,1 depending if > or < than 50% arc. But this does not seem to be the case?

Comment: nevermind! I had made a stupid mistake in the way I was calculating segment %. All working now!!

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 possible solution for arcs connecting two points.
In the image below

- the blue arcs are drawn counter clockwise, the green arcs clockwise (sweep flag)
- the small blue arch is drawn counter clockwise around the center of the green circle
- the large blue arch is drawn counter clockwise around the center of the bleu circle.
- the small green arch is drawn clockwise around the center of the blue circle
- the large green arch is drawn cclockwise around the center of the green circle
  the darker arcs are small arcs, the lighter arcs are large arcs (large-arc flag)

to tell the render which arc you want, you use a combination of large-arc and sweep flag. The sweep flag determines the direction (clockwise, counter clockwise) the large arc flag deteremines the size (large arch, small arc)

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="-150 -250  400 400">


  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5">
    <path d="M25.88 -96.59 A100 100 0 0 0 96.59 -25.88" stroke="darkblue" />
    <path d="M25.88 -96.59 A100 100 0 1 0 96.59 -25.88" stroke="lightblue" />
    <path d="M25.88 -96.59 A100 100 0 0 1 96.59 -25.88" stroke="darkgreen" />
    <path d="M25.88 -96.59 A100 100 0 1 1 96.59 -25.88" stroke="lime" />
  </g>
  <g fill="red" stroke="red">
    <circle cx="25.88" cy="-96.59" r="5" />
    <circle cx="96.59" cy="-25.88" r="5" />
  </g>
</svg>
<br/>
<ul>
  <li>
    the blue arcs are drawn counter clockwise, the green arcs clockwise (sweep flag)
  </li>
  <li>
    the small blue arch is drawn counter clockwise around the center of the green circle
  </li>
  <li>
    the large blue arch is drawn counter clockwise around the center of the bleu circle.
  </li>
  <li>
    the small green arch is drawn clockwise around the center of the blue circle
  </li>
  <li>
    the large green arch is drawn cclockwise around the center of the green circle
  </li>
  <li>the darker arcs are small arcs, the lighter arcs are large arcs (large-arc flag)</li>
</ul>
```